Calculating/enumerating the euclidean projection between two spheres
Let

$P \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite set of $n$-dimensional euclidean points;
$r_p \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ be the radius of the sphere centered at $p \in P$; And
$c_p = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x - p\|_2 \leqslant r_p^2 \}$ be the sphere centered at $p$.

Let $p_1$ and $p_2 \in P$ be two distinct points.
We define as the sphere euclidean projection between these two points the minimum solution for the following program.
$\min \| x - y \|_2$
s.t.

$\|x - p_1 \|_2 = r_{p_1}^2$
$\|x - p_2 \|_2 = r_{p_2}^2$

For instance, let's take a look at the figure below.

The extremities of the drawn line, would be the solution for the points $x$ and $y$ of the presented program.
Another example, is the one below.

Where the blue dots are the solutions for the presented program.
For the case in which $c_{p_1}$ and $c_{p_2}$ share no common space, there is a single minimum cost solution $(x, y)$ for the program. Otherwise, the number of minimum cost solutions $(x, y)$ is at most 2, cf. the second figure.
My question is: Given the two aforementioned points $p_1$ and $p_2$, is there any way of calculating and enumerating the minimum cost solutions (the resulting projected points) for the sphere euclidean projection between their respective spheres $c_{p_1}$ and $c_{p_2}$?

Let $\delta=p_2-p_1$, and $d=\delta/\|\delta\|$.

If $\|\delta\| \ge r_{p_1}+r_{p_2}$, then there is a single solution, namely $x=p_1+r_{p_1}d$ and $y=p_2-r_{p_2}d$.

If $\|\delta\| < r_{p_1}+r_{p_2}$, then there are multiple solutions.  Specifically, if $n=2$, then there are two solutions, and if $n\ge 3$, there are infinitely many solutions (they lie on a $n-2$-sphere).  You can find all solutions by letting $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ denote the coordinates of a single solution, and noting that it must lie on both spheres, hence $\|x-p_1\|^2 = r_{p_1}^2$ and $\|x-p_2\|^2=r_{p_2}^2$.  The solution to this pair of quadratic equations give the location of those points.



Thank you so much for the comment. When you use $c_{p}$ are you actually referring to $p$?

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade, oops, yes, exactly!  My apologies.  I have revised my answer accordingly.

Thank you so much.
